# Firebase validation make sure child exists and has correct value on initial write and update

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How would I ensure the email and created fields are always present and email has a valid email value at all times? If I use newData.hasChildren(['email','created']) this would fail on an update if I was only updating the email field for the record.

```
"uPrivate": {
    "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".validate": "root.child('u/'+$uid).exists()",
        "email": {
            ".validate": "root.child('u/'+$uid).exists()",
        },
        "created": {
            ".validate": "root.child('u/'+$uid).exists()",
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newData` variable contains the new data at the location as it will exist after the write. From the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data):

> the `newData` variable contains the new data that will exist if the write operation is successful. newData represents the merged result of the new data being written and existing data.

So for any data that is not in the update, it will contain the existing value.